# rspec testing ajax response (should render a partial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I want to test that my controller action is rendering a partial.

I've poked around and I can't seem to find anything that works.

create action:

```
def create
  @project = Project.new...
  respond_to do |format|
    if @project.save
      format.js { render :partial => "projects/form" }
    end
  end
end
```

spec:

```
it "should save and render partial" do
  ....
  #I expected/hoped this would work
  response.should render_partial("projects/form")
  #or even hopefully
  response.should render_template("projects/form")
  #no dice
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update*** see bluefish's answer below, it seems to be the correct answer

Would you consider using [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) for your integration testing?  I found ajax difficult to test with rspec alone.  In your case I'm not even sure you are getting a response back yet.  In capybara it waits for the ajax call to finish and you can call the page.has_xxxx to see if it was updated.  Here is an example:

```
it "should flash a successful message" do
    visit edit_gallery_path(@gallery)
    fill_in "gallery_name", :with => "testvalue"
    click_button("Update")
    page.has_selector?("div#flash", :text => "Gallery updated.")
    page.has_content?("Gallery updated")
    click_link "Sign out"
end
```

Answer (score 49):

If you're looking for a REAL answer... (i.e. entirely in RSpec and not using Capybara), the RSpec documentation says that render_template is a wrapper on assert_template. assert_template ([according to the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Assertions/ResponseAssertions/assert_template)) also indicates that you can check that a partial was rendered by including the :partial key.

Give this a go...

```
it { should render_template(:partial => '_partialname') }
```

Comment: @BlueFish, I think your answer is right, but it looks like his respond_to is doing the response in js.  Will this pick that up or do we need to add anything extra? I had some similar difficulty.

Comment: Works too well for me. render_template seems to pass whatever I put in (trying to test the default behavior of a controller)

Answer (score 1):

another great way to test your ajax controller method is to check the assignments which are later used to render the result. Here is a little example:

Controller

```
def do_something
  @awesome_result = Awesomeness.generete(params)
end
```

JBuilder

```
json.(@awesome_result, :foo, :bar)
```

Rspec Controller Test

```
describe :do_something do

  before do
    @valid_params{"foo" => "bar"}
  end

  it "should assign awesome result" do
    xhr :post, :do_something, @valid_params
    assigns['awesome_result'].should_not be_nil
  end

end
```